# I have an action that happens every two weeks, how can I count how many times it happens in a a month?

Tags: python, datetime

Just learning this kind python, and I am trying to write a program that will generate the bills I need to send to clients each month.

Most clients have a service once a week, so that is easy to count if they have 4 or 5 in a month.

But some clients have a service every two weeks.  So I can't just count how many Mondays (for example) in the month.  If there are 5 Mondays in the month, I need to be able to check if they had a service on the 1st, 3rd and 5th Monday of the month, or on the 2nd and 4th of the month.

I guess I have to include a include some reference to a date they did have class, then count from then, rather than just getting the days for the current month?

Here's what I have so far

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

def main():

    weekdays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    counted_days = defaultdict(int)
    
    #count days in month
    now = datetime.now()
    total_days = calendar.monthrange(now.year, now.month)[1]

    #count the instances of individual days
    for i in range(total_days):
        counted_days[calendar.weekday(now.year, (now.month), (i+1))] +=1
```

The opening a CSV file with the clients service day.

I guess I will need to include a column in the CSV to have a 'confirmed service date' and calculate from from then when the first service in a month is carried out?

Comment: Pick your starting date.  Add 14 days to it, and see if the resulting date has the same month as your starting date.  Then do it again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.